# Programmatically define a new function from a list of other functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

I have:

```
def f(x, y): return x**2 + y**2
def g(x, y): return x**3 + y**3
def h(x, y): return x**4 + y**4
```

And I'd like to make a new function:

```
def J(x, y):
    return f(x,y)*g(x,y)*h(x,y)
```

However, I am unable to find a way to do this programmatically.
That is, take something like:

```
myFunctions = [f,g,h]
```

and return a new function `J` which returns the product of `f`, `g` and `h`.

Another wrinkle is that while `f`, `g` and `h` will always have an identical number of arguments, that number could change. That is, they could all have could have five arguments instead of two.

Desired behaviour:

```
print(J(2, 2)) # 4096
```

---

#### EDIT

The number of functions in `myFunctions` is also arbitrary.
I thought this was implied in my question, but upon rereading it I see that I did not make that at all clear. My apologies.

Comment: Any reason you don't define `J` as `def J(*args, **kwargs)` instead? Do you need the parameters for any other reason?

Comment: Do you create the list of functions? if it's so you can use `*args` to pass an optional number of positional arguments to your function.

Comment: You could use `functools.reduce`, `operator.mul`, `functools.partial` and other functional tooling in Python to do this. As other comments note, you can define arbitrary positional and keyword arguments easily.

Comment: @VincentSavard Not the names themselves, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function can accept arbitrarily many arguments using `*` like this:

```
def J(*args):
```

This will store all of `J`'s arguments in the list `args`. That list can then be converted back into multiple arguments to call other functions like this:

```
def J(*args):
  return f(*args) * g(*args)
```

This solves the problem of the number of arguments changing. So now let's handle the fact that there can be arbitrarily many functions. First we need to call the function in your list. We can just do that by iterating over them and using `()`:

```
def J(*args):
  return [func(*args) for func in myFunctions]
```

This will return a list of the functions' return values. So all we need now is to get the product of a collection:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def product(numbers):
  return reduce(mul, list, 1)

def J(*args):
  return product(func(*args) for func in myFunctions)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could allow `J` to take as many arguments as necessary, then multiply the final list that f, g, and h give:

```
def f(x, y): return x**2 + y**2

def g(x, y): return x**3 + y**3

def h(x, y): return x**4 + y**4

def multiply(mylist):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a*b, mylist)

myfuncs = [f,g,h]
def J(*args):
    return multiply([myfunc(*args) for myfunc in myfuncs])
```

Since f, g, and h will have the same amount of arguments, this should work for all cases.

Comment: Question is tagged Python 3, so you'll have to import `reduce` from itertools. Might as well also import operator.mul instead of building your own `multiply` function.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
from functools import reduce, partial
from operator import mul

def f(x, y): return x**2 + y**2
def g(x, y): return x**3 + y**3
def h(x, y): return x**4 + y**4

myFunctions = [f,g,h]

J = partial(lambda funcs, *args: reduce(mul, (func(*args) for func in funcs), 1), myFunctions)
print J(2, 2)
```

Has the nice property that J takes the same number of arguments as functions f, g & h rather than `*args`.

Comment: This doesn't use `myFunctions` though - it just hardcodes `f`, `g` and `h`.

Comment: Agreed, I've improved the answer (inspired by yours), thanks

Answer (score 0):

The variable number of arguments problem can be resolved by this:

```
def f(*args): return sum(map(lambda x: x**2, args))

def g(*args): return sum(map(lambda x: x**3, args))

def h(*args): return sum(map(lambda x: x**4, args))
```

And then you could simply define the `J` function

```
def J(*args):
    return f(*args)*g(*args)*h(*args)
```

If you want to support variable number of functions, then you could define J as the following and pass in the list of functions as the first item of the list and the arguments as the following items.

```
def J(*args):
    funcs = args[0]            
    args = args[1:]           
    temp = map(lambda x: x(*args), funcs)
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, temp, 1)
```